# Neo4j keeping bound variables after unwind with comprehension list that returns null

Tags: neo4j

I found this old bug listing in github, and mainly seeking confirmation that this is a feature. Is there a workaround? https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5851

```
MATCH (rememberMe)
WITH rememberMe
UNWIND [(rememberMe)-[:hates]->(icecream) | icecream]
 +  [(rememberMe)-[:vomits]->(cookies) | cookies]
 AS noSuchThing
RETURN rememberMe
```

rememberMe is lost when noSuchThing is null

Is there a way to get around this? Can't seem to get the CASE WHEN NULL to work with sum of comprehension list.

Comment: can you please share what are you trying to achieve so I can suggest a solution. In your query, you are not using the value of `noSuchThing` so what is the meaning of finding it?

Comment: Yes - I am seeking noSuchThing to run another similar unwind, so optional match with collect would not work. InverseFalcon hit the nail on the head below. I need to separate the comprehension list from the unwind with a list, then do the unwind case when null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the UNWIND behavior on an empty list is expected. UNWIND emits a row per element in a list, so if there are no list elements, no rows will be emitted, effectively wiping out the original row.

As you mentioned in the documentation there is a workaround using CASE to use a `[null]` list in place of an empty list so you retain a single list element and the original row remains.

For your case, you'll want to slow down a bit, you're trying to do many things at once, so separate the creation of the list from the UNWIND and you should be able to apply the workaround:

```
MATCH (rememberMe)
WITH rememberMe, [(rememberMe)-[:hates]->(icecream) | icecream]
 +  [(rememberMe)-[:vomits]->(cookies) | cookies]
 AS list
UNWIND CASE WHEN size(list) = 0 THEN [null] ELSE list END as noSuchThing
RETURN rememberMe
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally got stuck on placing the comprehension list in the unwind.